# Gravity forms and Ideal postcodes

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Wondering if anyone can help me with field population in gravity forms WP and Ideal postcodes auto address.

I've been following these 2 guides but can't seem to get it working just right

https://docs.ideal-postcodes.co.uk/docs/address-finder/single-field
https://docs.ideal-postcodes.co.uk/docs/integrations/gravity-forms

I have 5 fields in GF. Address line 1, address line 2, address line 3, city/town and postcode.

When choosing an address from the auto complete, each field is populated correctly but I want to be able to populate the full address into the first field address line 1

Heres the script i have and it seems to only populate address line 1 into address line 1 not the full address.

Thanks

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        IdealPostcodes.AddressFinder.setup({
          apiKey: "#MY-API-KEY",
          outputFields: {
            line_1: 'input[name="input_10"]',
            line_2: 'input[name="input_13"]',
            line_3: 'input[name="input_17"]',
            post_town: 'input[name="input_15"]',
            postcode: 'input[name="input_14"]'
          },
          onAddressRetrieved: (address) => {
            const result = [
              address.line_1,
              address.line_2,
              address.line_3,
              address.post_town,
              address.postcode
            ]
              .filter((elem) => elem !== "")
              .join(", ");
            document.getElementById('input_26_10').value = result;
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the outputFields.

```
         outputFields: {
            line_1: 'input[name="input_10"]',
            line_2: 'input[name="input_13"]',
            line_3: 'input[name="input_17"]',
            post_town: 'input[name="input_15"]',
            postcode: 'input[name="input_14"]'
          },
```

and add an `inputField: '#input_26_10',`

Documentation: https://docs.ideal-postcodes.co.uk/docs/address-finder/single-field